# How to prerender content with Nuxt Js from own Api?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store

`/store/articles.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  article:'',
})
export const mutations = {
  setArticle(state, payload) {
    state.article= payload.data;
  }
}
export const actions = {
  async getArticle ({ commit }, id) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('http://test.local/api/getArticle',id);
      commit('setArticle', { data })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

my API returns a JSON like example this

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "some title",
  "content": "some content",
  "image": "article_img1.jpg"
}
```

there is my page and content from API

`/pages/article/slug.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div> 
    <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
    <img :src="'/images/'+article.image" />
  <div v-html="article.content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed:{
      article(){
        return this.$store.dispatch('getArticle',1)
      },
  },
}
</script>
```

Content appears fine,
but when I look at the content page code, there is no content.
How to make the content prerendered, on this way?

And how to generate static pages from an API, do I need to use [@nuxt/content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) ? I am trying this, but it looks like works only from `.md` or `.json` files, I don't understand how to generate automatically with some API fetching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async asyncData({params, store}) {
      articles: await store.dispatch('articles/articlesById', {'id': params.id, 
      return {articles};
    },
```

this works

and i make
ssr true in config

Answer (score 1):

You can totally generate pages from an API without the need of `nuxt/content`. I have written an in-depth answer here: [Rewriting to a 404 page doesn't work if the page doesn't exist on a site created with SSG in Nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68417337/8816585)

Showing how to achieve a clean generation of your pages during build time.
Otherwise, you can also follow the steps described into the documentation here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-which-returns-a-promise

Also, be sure to have `ssr` set to `true` in your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the nuxt `asyncData` hook for that.

```html
<template>
  <div> 
    <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
    <img :src="'/images/'+article.image" />
  <div v-html="article.content" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
      articles() {
          return this.$store.state.article
      }
  },
  async asyncData() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('getArticle',1)
  },
}
</script>
```

This will make nuxt wait on the server for the promise to resolve.

Comment: This will not prerender it ahead of time.

Comment: async asyncData({params, store}) {
      articles: await store.dispatch('articles/articlesById', {'id': params.id, 
      return {articles};
    },
this works

Comment: Yes that depends on implementation. Feel free to "edit" my answer and accept if it helped