# NuxtJS: routes working in dev but not production (netlify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

Still very much learning JS, but I'm struggling with this issue.

In the VS code debug environment, everything works, but when I deploy to Netlify, some routes work only sometimes.  For example, [this route](http://brianssparetime.com/interests/film-photography), along with the other /interests routes, either 404s, loads a blank page, or occasionally just works.

The code behind those pages is [here](https://github.com/brianssparetime/blog/blob/master/pages/interests/_slug.vue).  The other nuxt-content pages in /posts, /tags, and /wip all work fine.

I get no errors that I can see related to this in the dev environment.  I'm still new to js troubleshooting, but when I load up dev tools in Chrome, I sometimes see an error "DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method."

I've researched that error leading me to a few posts on the topic:

- [Nuxtjs issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1594)
- [Vuejs error on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re)
- [Hydration errors blog pos](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/vue-hydration-error/)
- [failed to execute 'appendChild' node](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5800)
- [full static mode dynamic pages payload 404 errors](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7717)

I've tried various solutions from there including replacing v-if with v-show, and cleaning up `<p>` tags, and wrapping various things in `<client-only>` but the problem persists.

Anyone have insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your issue, the fixed blog can be seen here
https://brians-spare-time-blog.netlify.app/interests/film-photography/

In your `Sidebar.vue` file you do have

```html
<template>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div
      v-if="isPanelOpen"
      class="sidebar-backdrop"
      @click="closeSidebarPanel"
    />
    <transition name="slide">
      <div v-if="isPanelOpen" class="sidebar-panel">
        <slot />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `slot` is then used into a `layouts/default.vue` with the following

```html
<Sidebar>
  <ul class="sidebar-panel-nav" @click="closeSidebarPanel">
    <li>
      &#8226;
      <nuxt-link to="/interests/film-photography">
        Film Photography
      </nuxt-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</Sidebar>
```

So, Nuxt crawler should be able to generate it but for some reason, having

```html
<div v-if="isPanelOpen">
```

is a blocker for him. This probably have to do with the way you're managing your Vuex store here. You could debug more in depth to see why this is not handling the state properly, [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) could be useful for this.

Meanwhile, here is a quick fix

```html
<div v-show="isPanelOpen">
```

This way, the sidebar will always be in the DOM and it helps the crawler doing it's job properly. As you can see, your blog is now live.

Using `yarn generate` could be a quick debugger because it will point out if the page you're wanting is actually generated or not.

[image]

Otherwise, you could also [generate the pages manually in your `nuxt.config.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431975/8816585) but this is pretty overkill in your situation.

---

PS: you do have some ESlint errors in your `nuxt.config.js`, `build` key.
I do recommend fixing those. Or any ESlint errors tbh.